# Compare two columns and list a third column

Tags: excel, excel-formula, string-matching

I have a excel sheet which has 3 Columns

```
A  B   C    D
1  A   1
2  B   3
3  C   4
       6
5  D

7  E
```

I want to check column c for values present in column A and lost corresponding values of column B  in Column D

```
Result:

A  B   C    D
1  A   1    A
2  B   3    C
3  C   4
       6
5  D

7  E
```

I have acieved the first part by doing

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(C1,A:A,0)),"True","False")
```

This lists `True` besides the value on Column C values in COlumn A. I am unsure how to do the other part though formulka. Can I get some suggestions please.

Comment: Vlookup() can do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use v lookup as:

=Vlookup (C2,$A$2:$B$8,2,False)

Comment: Thanks , I used `=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(C2,A:B,2,0),"Error")`